# Hashmap error: incompatible types

Tags: java, hashmap, bluej

I made a hashmap that stores roman numerals as keys and their decimal numbers as values.  The error says "incompatible types - found java.lang.Object but expected int".  I'm just trying to get the value of the roman numeral when I write "conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));" What am I doing wrong here?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class test
    {
        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        static HashMap conversions = new HashMap();
        public static void main(String args[]){
            conversions.put('I',1);
            conversions.put('V',5);
            conversions.put('X',10);
            conversions.put('L',50);
            conversions.put('C',100);
            conversions.put('D',500);
            conversions.put('M',1000);

            String numOne = "XIX";

            for(int x = 0; x <= numOne.length()-2; x++){
                int temp1 = conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));
                int temp2 = conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x+1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use raw type `HashMap`. Make is a parameterized type.

Comment: And you should post entire error messages, not just snippets.

Comment: @chrylis that was the entire error message

Comment: It also specifies *where* the error is, whether it's compile-time or runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line:

```
static HashMap conversions = new HashMap();
```

to

```
static Map<Character,Integer> conversions = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
```

or as of Java 7, we can avoid some duplication by doing the following

```
static Map<Character,Integer> conversions = new HashMap<>();
```

All in all, this will autobox your primitives and resolve your problem

Comment: thanks, I was trying to do <char,int>, so I see what I did wrong

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: unfortunately Java generics only handle reference types and both `char` and `int` are primitives types, so you can't use them here. Fortunately auto-boxing and auto-unboxing hides most of that from you.

Comment: Thanks :) I've now also included the Java 7 syntax in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making proper use of generics, you can tell Java what your `HashMap` is supposed to contain:

```
static HashMap<Character,Integer> conversions = new HashMap<>();
```

This would make your code compile, as the compiler would know that `conversions.get()` returns an `Integer` (and that can automatically be converted to an `int` via auto-unboxing).

Prior to Java 7, you'd need to repeat the types for the initialization as well, making it `new HashMap<Character,Integer>()`.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap stores and returns Objects and you cannot assign an object to a primtive directly:

```
 int temp1 = conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));
 int temp2 = conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x+1));
```

try this instead:

```
int temp1 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));
int temp2 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x+1));
```

or better use parameterized Map to avoid the cast during retrieval of objects:

```
static HashMap<Character, Integer> conversions = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Comment: Note that the compiler would be able to unbox a properly parameterized `Map` variable.

Comment: While this *would* solve the problem, that's the old (pre-generics) way. He should really use a propperly typed `HashMap` instead of the raw type.

Comment: @chrylis yes but for raw map it will not.

Comment: Its not the best solution but still it will work. Why would people downvote a working solution?

Comment: @Lokesh: because it's not the best solution. Teaching a beginner the *sub-optimal* approach first without a good reason will only lead to a developer who thinks that's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the value to an object. As others already suggested use like

```
for(int x = 0; x <= numOne.length()-2; x++){
    int temp1 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));
    int temp2 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x+1));
}
```

With this I also recommend to declare the Hashmap like following

```
static Map<String, Integer> conversions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x = 0; x <= numOne.length()-2; x++){
                int temp1 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x));
                int temp2 = (Integer) conversions.get(numOne.charAt(x+1));
                System.out.println(temp1 + "   "+temp2);
```

Use this, output is -

10   1
1   10